# Blank Date Parameter Rather than using 'Allow Null' Checkbox

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I will try to be as clear as possible with what I need here. Basically, I have 'FromDate' and 'ToDate' parameters. By default, I want these parameters to include ALL date/times. I can achieve this by checking the 'Allow Nulls', and handling the NULL in the main stored procedure. Unfortunately, business users will not understand what the Null checkbox means. Also, I can set the default dates to be the earliest and latest dates SQL Server supports, but this is ugly. Thus, I need a work around.
I need some way to have these parameters default to a blank value such that when I run the report, I immediately get records back regardless of the date. Then, if the user wants to adjust the date, they should be able to click the Calendar icon and choose From and To Dates (The parameter MUST stay Datetime).
Any ideas?

Comment: A datetime can't be a "blank value". An empty string will be implicitly cast to 1900-01-01. Why is using defaults an ugly solution when the parameter is optional?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Just saw you're using SSRS - can you make the textbox containing the from_date an expression:

```
=iif(Parameters!from_date="1753-01-01","",Parameters!from_date)
```

For the UI or report, can you just mask the SQL min date value as an empty string or "select date..." string?

```
if from_date_in_sql = '1753-01-01' then
    from_date_on_report = ""
end if
```

Since this would only affect the way the report/UI displays the date, you don't have to allow NULL dates in the SQL table. On saving, you would have to do the opposite..if from_date_on_report = "" then set from_date_to_save_to_SQL_table = '1753-01-01'

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to mask the parameter label, as I still need the calendar pop-out to work :/

Answer (score 0):

I would make the parameters optional on the report by making changes in the stored procedure.

If the users do not select a date make sure null or no value is passed to the parameter (it is set to null as default) , if they do select a date the date value should be passed to the procedure and your procedure should look something like.....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_report_Sp
  @StartDate DATE = NULL
 ,@EndDate   DATE = NULL
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   Declare @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql = N' SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE 1 = 1 '
        + CASE WHEN @StartDate IS NOT NULL
          THEN N' AND DateColumn >= @StartDate' ELSE N'' END
        + CASE WHEN @EndDate IS NOT NULL
          THEN N' AND DateColumn <= @EndDate' ELSE N'' END        

Exec sp_executesql @Sql 
                  ,N'@StartDate DATE,@EndDateDATE '
                  ,@StartDate
                  ,@EndDate

END
```